# Trouble escaping double quotes in Azure pipelines DotNetCoreCLI task

Tags: .net-core, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-yaml, dotnet-publish

I'm trying to publish my .NET web app using the somewhat new built-in container support for the .NET SDK. In order to set the container image tags I need to pass a parameter in the arguments. This parameter needs to look like `-p ContainerImageTags='"1.0.0;latest"'`, note the double quotes surrounded by the single quotes, it needs it that way for some reason.

So I would think the following would just work, but it doesn't. Now I'm using a block scalar for the arguments, which, if I'm not mistaken should leave my quotes alone, so no need to escape them.

```yaml
  - task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
    displayName: 'Publish'
    inputs:
      command: 'publish'
      arguments: >-
        -p PublishProfile="DefaultContainer"
        -p ContainerRepository="my-repository"
        -p ContainerImageTags='"$(Build.BuildNumber);latest"'
        -p Version="$(Build.BuildNumber)"
```

But the output of this is:

```bash
/usr/bin/dotnet publish /home/vsts/work/1/s/src/the-web-project.csproj -p PublishProfile=DefaultContainer -p ContainerRepository=my-repository -p ContainerImageTags='2023.12.07.18;latest' -p Version=2023.12.07.18
```

so no double quotes. Thus, escaping the quotes like `/"` results in the following:

```bash
/usr/bin/dotnet publish /home/vsts/work/1/s/src/the-web-project.csproj -p PublishProfile=\DefaultContainer" -p ContainerRepository="my-repository" -p ContainerImageTags='"2023.12.07.19;latest"' -p Version="2023.12.07.19"
```

This is kinda better, except the first quote is just `\` now, breaking the command. Only using escaped quotes on the ContainerImageTags just moves the problem creating `-p ContainerImageTags='\2023.12.07.19;latest"'`.

But then again, the YAML docs say escaping is unnecessary in block scalars. So, doing the same but with the Bash@3 task instead actually does what I want.

```bash
exec bash '/home/vsts/work/1/s/test' -p PublishProfile="DefaultContainer" -p ContainerRepository="my-repository" -p ContainerImageTags='"2023.12.07.18;latest"' -p Version="2023.12.07.18"
```

How do I get my quotes properly with the DotNetCoreCLI@2 task?

Comment: Hi @Johan B, hope you are well! Have checked the suggestion shared by Bright? Tested from my side, `-p ContainerImageTags="\"$(Build.BuildNumber);latest\""` works. If it works for you. it's suggested that you accept his answer below according to [How does accepting an answer work](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work/5235#5235). Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set the **`arguments`** like as below on the **`DotNetCoreCLI@2`** task.

```yaml
  - task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
    displayName: 'Publish'
    inputs:
      command: 'publish'
      arguments: >-
        -p PublishProfile="DefaultContainer"
        -p ContainerRepository="my-repository"
        -p ContainerImageTags="\"$(Build.BuildNumber);latest\""
        -p Version="$(Build.BuildNumber)"
```

[image]

Comment: @JohanB, Is there any update from you?

Comment: Yes, this does indeed work properly :) Thank you for the help.

Answer (score 1):

You can try to use `-p ContainerImageTags="'\"$(Build.BuildNumber);latest\"'"`.

In the log, I can see the following:

[image]

Comment: Yes, this looks a lot better. However, in the log, I now get `Building image 'my-repository' with tags '' on top of base image 'mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:8.0'.`, so the tags are not passed on correctly. Trying the command from the logs on my local machine (inside my WSL2 Ubuntu) does get the tags as expected :(

Comment: @JohanB, See the solution in my answer. I have tested it. It is able to work as expected.